# Gatsby deployment failed on netlify with error code 127

Tags: javascript, gatsby, netlify, contentful-api

I am trying to deploy a gatsby project on netlify using github. Everything work fine but at the end i am facing these issue.

`9:32:45 AM: node: symbol lookup error: /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-source-contentful/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node: undefined symbol: vips_foreign_heif_compression_get_type
9:32:45 AM: Skipping functions preparation step: no functions directory set
9:32:45 AM: Caching artifacts
9:32:45 AM: Started saving node modules
9:32:45 AM: Finished saving node modules
9:32:45 AM: Started saving pip cache
9:32:45 AM: Finished saving pip cache
9:32:45 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
9:32:45 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
9:32:45 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
9:32:45 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
9:32:45 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
9:32:45 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
9:32:45 AM: Started saving go dependencies
9:32:45 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
9:32:48 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
9:32:48 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
9:32:49 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 127
9:32:49 AM: Finished processing build request in 1m36.385195021s`

How to fix symbol lookup error: /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-source-contentful/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp.node: undefined symbol: vips_foreign_heif_compression_get_type

Comment: Are your queries running on `gatsby develop` command?

Comment: yes it is running without any error. Project is working fine on localhost

Comment: I'm too having the same issue, could be related to package versions.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a conflict in package versions, there seems to be a version miss-match. Solved it by updating all the packages

```
npm update
```

Comment: Yes! there was some packages that need to be update, i tried npm update but is did not fix them all so i have to read the log file and update manually 3 or 4 package and it worked. 